# Which treasure is worth the most gold?

Tags: ios, scurvy-scallywags

Some of the map spots in Scurvy Scallywags are timed bonus areas with multiple types of gold - coin piles, gold bars, and (IIRC) money sacks.  So that I can maximize my looting, which of the items is worth the most gold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The treasure levels (marked with an X on the map, of course) contain bronze coins, stacks of gold coins, money sacks and gold bars. Gold bars are worth the most, followed by sacks, then the gold stacks, and lastly the bronze coins.